# Numbered unique files

Tags: c++, file

I would like to create unique files, appending a number to their name if neccessary (similar to how browsers usually name downloaded files).

Here is what I am trying to do, but with directories (using the [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) library) :

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

template <typename... Args> std::string concatenate(Args&&... args) {
    std::ostringstream sstr;
    (sstr << ... << std::forward<Args>(args));
    return sstr.str();
}

fs::path unique_dir(const fs::path &base, unsigned max_tries) {
    if(fs::create_directories(base))
        return base;

    for(unsigned i = 1; i < max_tries; ++i) {
        fs::path p = base;
        p += concatenate('_', i);

        if(fs::create_directory(p))
            return p;
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("unique_dir: gave up");
}

int main() {
    unique_dir("my_dir", 3); // creates my_dir
    unique_dir("my_dir", 3); // creates my_dir_1
    unique_dir("my_dir", 3); // creates my_dir_2
    unique_dir("my_dir", 3); // throws
}
```

How can I do the same with files ?

Some precisions :

- It does not need to be highly-performing (it is for a very cold part of the code)
- Non-cross-platform is fine, as long as there is a variant for Linux, Windows and Mac
- I do not want to use a [`mkstemp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp)-type function that would require to put a non-user-friendly id in the filename

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to get a smaller program working first, that prints out the random filenames.  Get this working first.  After this works, you can pass the file name to the appropriate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for POSIX systems, using [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

```
#include <fcntl.h> // open()
#include <unistd.h> // close()

fs::path unique_file(const fs::path &base, unsigned max_tries) {
    fs::path p(base);

    for(unsigned i = 1; i <= max_tries; ++i) {
        // O_CREAT | O_EXCL will create the file if it does not exist, and fail otherwise
        // 0666 : Read + Modify permissions for everybody
        int fd = open(p.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
        if(fd != -1) {
            if(close(fd) == -1) // We immediately close the file, which might be a waste
                throw fs::filesystem_error("unique_file: POSIX close() error", p, std::error_code(errno, std::generic_category()));

            return p;
        }

        // EEXIST is set if open() failed because the file already existed
        if(errno != EEXIST)
            throw fs::filesystem_error("unique_file: POSIX open() error", p, std::error_code(errno, std::generic_category()));

        errno = 0;
        p = base.parent_path() / base.stem();
        p += concatenate('_', i);
        p += base.extension();
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("unique_file: gave up");
}
```

Windows seems to offer the [`_sopen_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sopen-s-wsopen-s?view=vs-2019) function which offers the same `_O_CREAT | _O_EXCL` flag combination.

Answer (score 0):

With directories, you are checking if the creation of a directory worked. With files you can achieve this effect by checking if the particular path is pointing at an [existing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) file, and if not, then creating it:

```
fs::path unique_file(const fs::path &base, unsigned max_tries) {
    if(!fs::exists(base)) {
       std::ofstream ofs(base);
       return base;
    }

    for(unsigned i = 1; i < max_tries; ++i) {
        fs::path p = base;
        p += concat() << '_' << i;

        if(!fs::exists(p)) {
            std::ofstream ofs(p);
            return p;
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("unique_file: gave up");
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I would encounter the risk (albeit very small) of another instance of my program calling fs::exists() at the same time, and going with the same filename. Is there no way to avoid that risk ?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's true (but not 100% sure). Since performance is not a concern here (as stated in the question), you could manually take a lock here.

Comment: Are there locks that work between processes (not just threads) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm out of my depth on this one. I would guess that this is *possible*, but I couldn't really say *how*.

Comment: Well, while looking for a cross-process lock just I stumbled upon a function to open a file on Linux that fails if it exists (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20790/385247). Now I just need to look for the equivalent on other platforms. Thank you for your help !

Comment: No worries. If this solution actually ends up working, consider accepting it :)